# FPDF only print first return value while using query

Tags: php, fpdf

i want to make a detailed list of transaction, everything working fine except when buy 2 different item in 1 transaction, it print 1 detail item. I already make sure the query is giving the result the 2 item.

here is the code of printing detail content.

```
$q_invo = get_detail_transaction($r_invoice['transaction_id']);
$no = 1;
$hh = 5;
while ($r_invo = mysql_fetch_array($q_invo)) {
  $pdf->Cell(10, $hh+5, $no, 1, 0, 'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40, $hh+5, $r_invo['kode_barang'], 1, 0, 'C');
  $pdf->Cell(45, $hh+5, $r_invo['item_name'], 1, 0, 'C');
  $pdf->Cell(20, $hh+5, $r_invo['transaction_detail_qty_real'].
      '('.$r_invo['unit_utama_name'].')', 1, 0, 'C');

  $unit_id_utama = get_unit_id($r_invo['item_id']);
  $pdf->Cell(30, $hh+5, konversi_total_jumlah($unit_id_utama,
     $r_invo['item_id'],$r_invo['transaction_detail_qty_real'],
     $r_invo['transaction_detail_unit']), 1, 0, 'C');
  $item_id = $r_invo['item_id'];
  $where_item_id = "WHERE item_id = '$item_id' AND transaction_id = '$transaction_id'";
  $q_item_keterangan_details = select_config('transaction_details_item' ,$where_item_id);

  while ($r_item_keterangan_details = mysql_fetch_array($q_item_keterangan_details)) {
     $keterangan_item = $r_item_keterangan_details['keterangan_item'];
     $where_keterangan_item = "WHERE item_keterangan_details_id = '$keterangan_item'";
     $q_item_keterangan_details_id = select_config_by('item_keterangan_details', 
     'keterangan_details', $where_keterangan_item);
  }

  $pdf->Cell(55, $hh+5,$q_item_keterangan_details_id, 1, 0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40, $hh+5, format_rupiah($r_invo['transaction_detail_price']), 1, 0, 'R');
  $pdf->Cell(50, $hh+5, format_rupiah($r_invo['transaction_detail_price']*$r_invo['transaction_detail_qty']), 1, 0, 'R');
  $no++;

  $total_jml = $total_jml + $r_invo['transaction_detail_qty_real'];
  $total_berat = $total_berat + $r_invo['item_berat'];
  $hh = $hh + 5;
}
```

here is the query function :

```
function get_detail_transaction($id){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.unit_name AS unit_konversi_name, b.transaction_detail_unit,
                                            j.unit_name AS unit_utama_name, e.*, f.item_type_name, g.*
                                            FROM transactions a
                                            JOIN transaction_details b ON b.transaction_id = a.transaction_id
                                            JOIN items c ON c.item_id = b.item_id
                                            LEFT JOIN units d ON d.unit_id = b.transaction_detail_unit
                                            LEFT JOIN item_harga e ON e.item_id = b.item_id
                                            LEFT JOIN items_types f ON f.item_type_id = c.item_type
                                            LEFT JOIN item_details g ON g.item_id = b.item_id
                                            LEFT JOIN members h ON h.member_id = a.member_id
                                            LEFT JOIN units j ON j.unit_id = c.unit_id
                                            WHERE a.transaction_id = '$id' GROUP BY b.item_id");
return $query;
}
```

query above giving a result of 2 row. i tested it already.

Comment: It's better if you can show the SQL too.

Comment: give me a minute